# Правильный подход к освоению програмирования

Tags: веб-программирование, проектирование

Существует множество споров о "правильном" программировании, различных методах проектирования, парадигмах, шаблонах и т. д. Но как мне кажется, зачастую спорящие, особенно не имеющие достаточно большого опыта, не осознают что прежде чем "заморачиваться" на всех этих крутых фреймворках, парадигмах и методиках, необходимо освоить грамотное проектирование программ в обычном процедурном стиле, так как это делали, например, создатели используемых нами сегодня повсеместно операционных систем десятки лет назад. Ведь создание такого ПО как ОС немыслимо без тщательного ПРОЕКТИРОВАНИЯ. И делалось это все на языке C без всяких фреймворков и ООП. И так же, без этого немыслимо правильное использование всего многообразия современных высокоуровневых инструментов.

В связи с этим у меня возник вопрос - я понимаю что это вопрос опыта, но все же не подскажет ли кто хорошей книги по проектированию программ, как правильно распределять функционал по методам (ну и по классам если учитывать ООП)?

Comment: Читай вот [эту](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/26036833/) книгу, там есть ответы на твои сомнения.

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно посмотрю

Comment: вспоминаю, как недавно Торвальдс бомбанул и отправил на переписывание около миллиона строк ядра, ибо ему не понравился стиль программистов)

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы.

Активно используемая (и всюду преподаваемая ныне, как основная) [парадигма программирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) ООП "выкристаллизовалась" как результат анализа кода *успешных программ*, написанных в традиционной процедурной манере.

Насчет книг. Думаю вам стоит поискать *старые* (изданные до 90-го года) книги о *[структурном программировании](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)* (в [приложении](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) есть обширный список литературы).

Пожалуй, в первую очередь, я бы рекомендовал почитать Вирта, Йодана и Миллса.

В плане развития, обратите внимание на  [Donald Knuth. Structured Programming with go to Statements](https://web.archive.org/web/20130519122634/http://pplab.snu.ac.kr/courses/adv_pl05/papers/p261-knuth.pdf) и [Керниган Б., Пайк Р. Практика программирования](https://www.studmed.ru/kernigan-b-payk-r-praktika-programmirovaniya_7a1d6b47f6f.html)
(книжка реально хороша (как говорится, "Must Read")).